# Assign bindings to variables

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql, einstein

I'm working on a Einstein Analytics project, and I'm trying to get some bindings to be assigned to variables.

```
"q = load \"Dataset\";
 _value = foreach q generate ({{cell(S_Amount__1_USD.result, 0, \"sum_S.Amount_c_USD\" ).asObject()}}); 
_target = foreach q generate ({{cell(TargetToDateSAQL_USD.result, 0, \"count\" ).asObject()}}); 
a = (_value / _target) as 'calc';
a = limit a 1;"
```

Unfortunately this is not working. The error I receive is the following:
Syntax Error at position 255 after token as a⇾s⇽

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the bindings in the calc field itself.

```
q = load \"Dataset\";
a = foreach q generate ({{cell(S_Amount__1_USD.result, 0, \"sum_S.Amount_c_USD\" ).asObject()}} / {{cell(TargetToDateSAQL_USD.result, 0, \"count\" ).asObject()}}) as 'calc';
```